# ios terminal github port 443. Operation timed out

Tags: ios, git, terminal

Why would it be every time I try to install from ios terminal I get a message like:

port 443: Operation timed out.

I'm new to using github. Do I need an account (username/password) with them.

Basically all I've done is open terminaland typed curl -v https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt.git.

Can anyone help me with this. I've googled for ages but none of the suggestions work.

I tried setting the proxy by

export http_proxy="myproxyaddresshere:8080"

Comment: did you try doing `$ git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt.git` ?

Comment: yeah, that works. Very confused.

Comment: Is that how you're supposed to install from github?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `$ git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt.git`

This would do!

> Do I need an account (username/password)

If you want to make changes to grunt or any project on github, you need a github account, then you have do something called forking the project.

Then you pull your forked copy of the project into your local system, make your desired changes and then push the changes to github.